# Easy ASP.NET HTTPS without official certificate and with minimum admin configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis, https

I need to encrypt passwords from the client sent to my API.  The normal way to do this is HTTPS, but I don't know if we have certificates etc.

What is the easiest to do this within my app, so it needs minimum admin configuration?

Is there some way I can do this with "client certificates" or "API keys"?

(I have looked at letsencrypt.org, but it seems to require something running on the server host)

Comment: It is a horrible idea to do HTTPS without a valid certificate. How can you ensure security then? And HTTPS has nothing to do with encrypting passwords. What exactly are you asking? Two separate questions?

Comment: @LexLi You are wrong, HTTPS will encrypt the traffic.

Comment: You can use a self-generated certificate but then the browser will complain about it. It will still encrypt but if the certificate is not 'trusted' on the client computer, the browser will complain. How many different clients (computers) will be using this?

Comment: I am now looking at this article describing  Oocx.ACME and Certes  https://medium.com/@MaartenSikkema/automatically-request-and-use-lets-encrypt-certificates-in-dotnet-core-9d0d152a59b5

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It is business clients, no browsers (And would browsers complain about calls to Web APIs).  Is this the same as I am referring to in my above comment? (You posted your comment around the same time as that  comment)

Comment: I've done a little bit of work on setting up IIS / Browsers with certificates, but nothing on setting up thick clients with certificates. I think the first thing to try is set up HTTPS in IIS with a self signed certificate and see what happens! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis#iis-manager.